# "=>" operator in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and has searched over here but didn't find the answer. I'm wondering what is this operator mean "x: => Boolean" in argument context of the function.

```
package scala
abstract class Boolean {
def && (x: => Boolean): Boolean 
def || (x: => Boolean): Boolean
}
```

I know that `def example(x: Int => Boolean): Boolean` would mean anonymous function that takes Int and return Boolean. However, what it means if argument omitted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it's passing parameter by name. means expression will be evaluated when parameter is accessed.

Comment: Important to know is, that it will be evaluated every time it is accessed as opposed to lazy evaluation that happens only the first time the field is accessed.

Answer (score 11):

It is actually syntactic sugar for a zero parameter function call:

```
x: () => Boolean
```

And as such x is not evaluated until the function is called so we get lazy evaluation of the parameter.

Every time that x is referenced in the body of the method it is re-evaluated. If you do not want this to happen you can do the following:

```
lazy val a = x
```

Adding the lazy keyword to the decalaration ensures that x is only evaluated when 'a' is first referenced.

Answer (score 10):

Its is referred as **[right arrow](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-for-java-programmers.html)**. It is also popluar by the name of **"fat arrow"**

The  right arrow `=>` separates the function’s argument list from its body.

Example:

```
object TimerAnonymous {
  def oncePerSecond(callback: () => Unit) {
    while (true) { callback(); Thread sleep 1000 }
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    oncePerSecond(() =>
      println("time flies like an arrow..."))
  }
}
```

The presence of an anonymous function in this example is revealed by the **right arrow => which separates the function’s argument list from its body.** In this example, the argument list is empty, as witnessed by the empty pair of parenthesis on the left of the arrow. The body of the function is the same as the one of timeFlies above.

Comment: () => Unit is a definition of anonymous function. In my case there's nothing on before fat arrow.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's lazy evaluation. You only evaluate the argument if needed. There's tons of articles to be found on scala lazy evaluation, e.g. http://louisbotterill.blogspot.com/2009/07/scala-lazy-evaluation-and-sieve-of.html

Comment: Well, this syntax "x: => Boolean" doesn't seems to be a lazy evaluation as it needs to be prefixed with lazy.

Comment: more precisely it's *call-by-name* argument